# Windows Phone: Venda com cartão de crédito

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone

Preciso realizar a venda com cartão de crédito através do meu aplicativo. Não gostaria que o cliente digitasse os seus dados no telefone, a venda seria feita pessoalmente.

Não serve a venda por uma "maquinhinha" do tipo "moderninha" do PagSeguro pois não tenho como obter os dados da venda (ao menos pelo que pesquisei). Mas se conseguir obter os dados captados do cartão pela máquina no meu app, já serve.

Sei que existe duas formas de obter os dados.

**1** - Ou através da leitura de dados pela maquininha de cartão ou um leitor de cartão (plug na entrada do fone de ouvido) usando um aplicativo oficial.

**2** - Ou usando a forma a cima porém com acesso ao aplicativo oficial (App2App) que o PagSeguro tem implementado apenas para Android. (outro exemplo [aqui](https://www.flint.com/docs/app2app/)) bastaria usar o leitor com plug no fone (acredito). Sugestão válida se achar algum app2app disponível para Windows phone.

Alguma solução?

Comment: Acho que não há tal recurso.. Poderia ser em compras no aplicativo, usando IAP da Microsoft, o usuário não precisaria digitar no app desde que tenha forma de pagamento configurada no telefone.

Comment: Inseri mais dados na pergunta.

Comment: Entendi um pouco mais, seria integrar o app com o adaptador de cartão? Vou pesquisar um pouco sobre o assunto. Desculpa comentar aqui mas não podia deixar de perceber que tu trabalha com WP, sabe como integrar o app com um sistema web? Tipo um aplicativo de site como o TecMundo? Vou pesquisar aobre sua duvida, portanto acho meio dificil pois a Microsoft não da muita liberdade de acesso, como citei, seria por IAP.

Comment: Certo, aguardo um retorno da sua pesquisa. Já fiz sim, dependendo da forma que você quer fazer a integração, é bem possível.

Comment: Pela minha pesquisa, como eu suspeitava, tal recurso não parece possível, seria indicado integrar o app com a Carteira do Windows Phone, pois assim até mesmo o usuário saberá que é mais seguro, achei um artigo interessante sobre isso: http://www.developer.com/ws/understanding-and-using-the-wallet-in-your-windows-phone-8-application.html  Sabe de algum tutorial ou artigo para mim iniciar a entender sobre essa integração?

Comment: A arteira não serve infelizmente. Pois serão muitos usuários diferentes usando o mesmo app, teria que ficar cadastrando cartão e tudo mais, sem chances.

Depende do tipo de integração, mais fácil você criar uma pergunta para isso e me pedir para responder.